# TypeScript: I have used a random name for variable and still error with "Cannot redeclare"

Tags: typescript

I am using - tsc Version 3.3.3333, trying to learn typeScript but a persistent error keeps showing.

even though I make sure the variable name is unique

```
let adasdasdasdasdasddf: string;
adasdasdasdasdasddf = "why error";
console.log(adasdasdasdasdasddf);
```

[image]

the error is this:

[image]

if I put **"export{};"** to solve this, another error will show in the browser:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at typeS_1.js:2*

is there a proper way to solve this without using "export{}"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare globals. Instead, put your variables within classes or as properties of an exported module. The correct way to do this is by scoping the variable and exporting that scope as a module.

For example:

```
let adasdasdasdasdasdd: String;      // Bad: Declared in global space shared by all

class myClass {
  public adasdasdasdasdasdd: String; // Good: Declared within the scope of instantiated objects
}

export {myClass};
```

*Bad*: In the above example, when this package is loaded/executed, it will declare `adasdasdasdasdasdd` globally. If the package is imported more than once, it will be reloaded and any globals will be redeclared. TypeScript is correctly notifying you since this could lead to obvious issues.

*Good*: On the other hand `myClass.adasdasdasdasdasdd` will only be declared once `myClass` objects are instantiated... living peacefully within their own scope.

**Alternative Solutions**

If you really don't want to use `export` and really do want to declare globals...

**1** Check to see if the global already exists and use it. The below code will declare the variable as a property on `window` (or `global` for node.js) (which is about as global as I would recommend) and reuse the value if it was previously declared... otherwise, initialize it.

```
window["adasdasdasdasdasdd"] = window["adasdasdasdasdasdd"] || ""; // For browser
global["adasdasdasdasdasdd"] = global["adasdasdasdasdasdd"] || ""; // For Node.js
```

AND/OR

**2** (Not Recommended) Just disable the TypeScript check for duplicate definitions within the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    ...
  }
}
```